# Kalanchoe seems to becoming soft and wilted

Tags: plant-health, succulents

I came by this stackexchange almost a year ago and had great success with folks giving me advice on my Kalanchoe, so I thought I'd come back with some more questions.

Over the past few months its been warm in Northern California (75-85deg F), but I haven't been changing my watering schedule which is once a week. It got a little burnt from a neem oil mishap last month as well.

I repotted this recently and I noticed that the bottom leaves were starting to get soft and yellowing a lot. Now the entire plant seems more wilted and soft, and I'm not sure if it's from overwatering or underwatering. The soil seems dry when I checked as well. Any suggestions on how I can rehab my kalanchoe?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it planted in that white pot? If so, does it have a drainage hole?

Comment: @Bamboo yes, it has a drainage hole! its small, but I've seen water seep out of the hole.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when a succulent-ish plant is soft and in dry soil, the course of action is to provide more water.

IMO, Plants need to be watered and fed based on their environmental conditions rather than a calendar. When it's 115 out I water my plants every other day. When it's 75, maybe once every two weeks. I know that's an extreme example, but its the same even if the temperature swings are smaller. When conditions change be prepared to change your methods.

Disclaimer: I'm a compulsive cactus grower in Arizona. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Oh, and as a safety precaution, take a couple of leaves and root them. There is a lot of information floating around on methods and practices.